# Quais são as boas práticas de implementação de Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Estou iniciando meus estudos em cima do Socket.io, precisamente em meu projeto envolvendo as tecnologias do vue/quasar, e gostaria de entender como se desenrola a lógica por trás destes seguintes fundamentos:

1. Como posso fazer o esquema de um usuário entrar em chat com outros usuários? (Eu entro como usuário X, mas quero conversar com os usuários Z e Y individualmente, X com Y, X com Z, mas não X com Y e Z)
   [Acredito que usando namespace e resgatando os ids de cada socket, mas qual é a melhor prática JS para isto?]
2. A listagem de quem está conectado e de quem não está, eu puxo eles pela conexão com o id de cada socket de usuário conectado dentro de uma array?
3. Dentro da chamada da função socket.on, é possível passar de um parâmetro ou preciso passar cada socket.on com seu devido parâmetro?

Já pesquisei pelo stackoverflow e alguns outros sites, mas ou não tem respostas que esclareçam essas minhas dúvidas ou são tão avançadas que ainda não consigo pegar a ideia ainda.
Agradeço desde já a atenção nesta grande dúvida minha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro, você precisaria de uma variável com os usuários conectados no server:

```
const users = {}
```

Depois tu precisas de um id para cada pessoa quando ela entra:

No client (a variável name pode ser um prompt ou uma input):

```
socket.emit('userConnected', { name: name })

socket.emit('userConnected', { reciver: reciverName, msg: input.value })
```

E no servidor, que está recebendo o emit:

```
io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
    socket.on('userConnected', (data)=>{
        users[data.name] = socket.id
    })
    socket.on('chat message', (data)=>{
        io.to(users[data.reciver]).emit('chat message', data.msg)
    })
})
```

Comment: demorou para receber resposta neh? kakakaka